# Find the word after specific word

Tags: javascript

i am new in javascript.
I have below code where textarea contains  text as...

```
<textarea id="myBox" >
{Picker:} Helper
This is just demo...
</textarea> 
<br/>
<span id="ans"></span> <br/>

<input type="button" onclick="getWord()" value="Click"/>
```

i am trying to find out the word exact after the `{Picker:}`, i.e. i want to find word `"Helper"`. So word  `{Picker:}` is the point from where i am starting to find immediate word after it. For this i using `indexOf`. What i did uptil now is ...

```
<script> 
    function getWord() {

        var val = $("#myBox").val();
        var myString = val.substr((val.indexOf("{Picker:}")) + parseInt(10), parseInt(val.indexOf(' ')) );
        $("#ans").text(myString);
    }
</script>
```

will anyone guide me to find what mistake i am making. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start from the index of `"{Picker:}"` + 9, because the length of the particular string is 9.

Parse till the the index of `'\n'` which is the line break character.

[`String.prototype.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) is deprecated, use [`String.prototype.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) instead.

```js
function getWord() {
  var val = $("#myBox").val();
  var myString = val.substring((val.indexOf("{Picker:}")) + 9, val.indexOf('\n'));
  $("#ans").text(myString);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="myBox">
{Picker:} Helper
This is just demo...
</textarea>
<br />
<span id="ans"></span> <br />

<input type="button" onclick="getWord()" value="Click" />
```

Comment: Sorry but i want only word Helper, not next after it

Comment: @PrakashJadhav Please check the updated answer.

Comment: sorry i didn't do it

Answer (score 0):

```
var val = $("#myBox").val();
console.log(val)
var tempArray = val.replace("\n", " ").split(" ");
var wordToFind;

for(var i = 0 ; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
    var word = tempArray[i];
  
  if (word == "{Picker:}") {
        wordToFind = tempArray[i + 1]
  }
}

console.log(wordToFind)
```

This will assign what ever word comes after Picker: to the wordToFind variable.
Check working :https://jsfiddle.net/o5qasnd0/14/

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this

```js
const text = "{Picker:} Helper";

const wordArr = text.split(' ');
const idx = wordArr.indexOf('{Picker:}');
console.log(idx != -1 && (idx + 1) < wordArr.length ? wordArr[idx + 1] : 'not found');
```